# Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a methode that loaded me the data from server on Json format data , also im using audioPlayer library to play music got it from server , when i want to pass the path inside  audioPlayer.play like that :

```
String Url = _loadedAudio[index]['file'];
await audioPlayer.play(Url);
```

it display to me this error  :

```
Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
```

how can i solve it

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're pointing to the wrong lines to know what causes the error

Comment: because, using the https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers package, you can't assign a String to the play method directly so this is an another error.

Comment: You should use a named parameter instead of a positional parameter. Assuming the method `audioPlayer.play` is the culprit method, do this instead: `await audioPlayer.play(url: Url);` or whatever the named parameter is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these two options:

```dart
await player.play(UrlSource(Url));
```

Or

```dart
await player.setSourceUrl(Url);
await player.resume();
```